# how to access to the bios in a thomson SP-HERO91.1BK32

Tags: bios

is there anyone know hoy to access to the BIOS in a thomson SP-HERO91.1BK32, because i want to reset windows and make it a new pc so i tried all the posible keys but I haven't made it
how to acces to the bios in a thomson SP-HERO91.1BK32

Comment: This is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.